# Adding Sticky header to div elements in same page automatically

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

I have some long divs all in one page, each with its own style. like this:

```
<div class="joe">
.... (pages of text)
</div>

<div class="harry">
...(pages of text)
</div>
```

any way to have the classname as a sticky header when a user scrolls through the text in each div? So if a person is scrolling inside the div with class:"joe" then the word "joe" would appear at the top of the screen until the user scrolls through to the end of the div. Then it disappears until he enters the next div which would display the classname of that div.

There are many dozens of such divs with various classnames so a manual solution won't work. needs to be automatic through css and/or js.

Comment: *to have the classname as a sticky header* ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes. what's not clear?

Comment: the whole sentence. What is a *classname* for you? what do you mean by *classname as a sticky header* ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok tried to clarify some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider data-attribute that you can convert to a pseudo element:

```css
div[data-name]::before{
   content:attr(data-name);
   display:block;
   position:sticky;
   top:0;
   text-align:center;
   background:red;
   font-size:20px;
}

body {
 max-width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="joe" data-name="joe">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at felis quis lacus fringilla suscipit vitae mollis eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus malesuada arcu efficitur, consectetur nunc nec, pulvinar odio.
  Morbi tincidunt nec erat vitae luctus. Cras elit ligula, rhoncus et feugiat quis, bibendum euismod nulla. Phasellus faucibus turpis erat, non bibendum tellus laoreet at. Vestibulum aliquam blandit lobortis. Nunc varius ac risus quis pharetra. In molestie,
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
</div>

<div class="harry" data-name="harry">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at felis quis lacus fringilla suscipit vitae mollis eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus malesuada arcu efficitur, consectetur nunc nec, pulvinar odio.
  Morbi tincidunt nec erat vitae luctus. Cras elit ligula, rhoncus et feugiat quis, bibendum euismod nulla. Phasellus faucibus turpis erat, non bibendum tellus laoreet at. Vestibulum aliquam blandit lobortis. Nunc varius ac risus quis pharetra. In molestie,
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
</div>
```

And you can add a small JS if you want to append automatically the data-attribute:

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll('div[class]');
for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
  all[i].setAttribute('data-name',all[i].className);
}
```

```css
div[data-name]::before{
   content:attr(data-name);
   display:block;
   position:sticky;
   top:0;
   text-align:center;
   background:red;
   font-size:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}

body {
 max-width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="joe" >
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at felis quis lacus fringilla suscipit vitae mollis eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus malesuada arcu efficitur, consectetur nunc nec, pulvinar odio.
  Morbi tincidunt nec erat vitae luctus. Cras elit ligula, rhoncus et feugiat quis, bibendum euismod nulla. Phasellus faucibus turpis erat, non bibendum tellus laoreet at. Vestibulum aliquam blandit lobortis. Nunc varius ac risus quis pharetra. In molestie,
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
</div>

<div class="harry" >
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at felis quis lacus fringilla suscipit vitae mollis eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus malesuada arcu efficitur, consectetur nunc nec, pulvinar odio.
  Morbi tincidunt nec erat vitae luctus. Cras elit ligula, rhoncus et feugiat quis, bibendum euismod nulla. Phasellus faucibus turpis erat, non bibendum tellus laoreet at. Vestibulum aliquam blandit lobortis. Nunc varius ac risus quis pharetra. In molestie,
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
  dui eu pulvinar commodo, justo metus auctor urna, vel ultrices nunc nisl in neque. Nullam at magna quis nibh lobortis euismod vel id augue. Nunc placerat sapien eget metus convallis, sed commodo dui interdum.
</div>
```

Comment: anyway to make it disappear automatically when user scrolls beyond the div? (may have other elements before the next div) preferably without adding some blank divs in between

Comment: @michael you can consider margin-bottom on the sticky element (check the update on the second snippet

Comment: anyway to make it disappear altogether? don't need it for all div elements

Comment: @michael I think the only why is to have margin between divs then

Comment: ok thanks. actually i see it does disappear when i scroll down below the div.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a header (the best way to do this is to use the new < header > tag added in HTML5) and in CSS you should add this:

```
header {
position: sticky;/*makes object sticky*/
top: 0;/*set header to the top of the page*/
z-index: 100;/*changes the header position to the front of the page*/
}
```

I hope that I helped